# How to display alert errors in Django

Tags: django, forms, validationerror

I've created a `clean_message` method in my `forms.py`, that checks if the `self.message` has something, and raises a `ValidationError` in case not.

```
"""
Comment
"""
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Comment field
    """
    comment = forms.CharField(
        widget = forms.Textarea(
            attrs = {
                'class': 'form-control',
                'rows': 2 
            }
        )
    )

    def clean_comment(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['comment'] is None:
            raise form.ValidationError({'comment': ['You must enter your comment'])
```

And this is the view file. What do I need to display the errors, built like shown above?

```
<form action="comment" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.comment.errors }}
        {{ form.comment }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Say it" class="btn btn-success"> 
    </div>
</form>
```

I've tried to use `{{ form.errors }}`, iterate over it, to use `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` etc, but none worked. I guess somehow I am reloading the form, and thus the messages aren't displayed.

Below is my `write_comment` method, the method executed when clicking on the button to post a comment:

```
def write_comment(request, post_id):
    """
    Write a new comment to a post
    """
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        post = Post.objects.get(pk = post_id)
        post.n_comments += 1
        post.save()

        comment = Comment()
        comment.comment = request.POST['comment']
        comment.created_at = timezone.now()
        comment.modified_at = timezone.now()
        comment.post_id = post_id
        comment.user_id = 2
        comment.save()
    else:
        form = CommentForm()

    return redirect(reverse('blog:post', args = (post_id,)))
```

Comment: I'd double check your form's `action`. Are you sure you're posting to the correct URL? On another note, there's no reason to do this kind of validation. Setting the `required` attribute to the field will take care of this for you.

Comment: I've put the `required` already and removed the `clean_comment` method. I've read somewhere that in order to display the errors, the form mustn't be reloaded, and I think this is exactly what's happening, but I don't know how to fix it. All I've tried so far didn't work.

Comment: There are at least two issues with the view. Firstly, by setting `form = CommentForm()` in the `else` statement, you are replacing the invalid form (with errors) with an empty form. Secondly, you should render a template which includes the form. You are redirecting instead.

Comment: @Alasdair I see. I made it like this because after commenting I wanted to return to the same page I was before, since it has parameters and I guess I cannot simply redirect to the specific template, because of the parameters.

Comment: It's tricky to redirect to the original page and still show the errors. You could manually create an error message using the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/). Another option is to use an ajax request from the original page, and show the errors using JavaScript. Both of these methods are more complex than the standard Django approach, which is to return a rendered template that includes the invalid form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the field to be required, just use `required=True`.

```
comment = CharField(
    required=True,
    widget = forms.Textarea(
        attrs = {
            'class': 'form-control',
            'rows': 2 
        }
    )
)
```

This way, there is no need to write a `clean_comment` method. Your current method is failing because `self.cleaned_data['comment']` is the empty string `''`, but you only show an error if it is `None`.

In the template, `{{ form.comment.errors }}` should work fine.

Comment: I think I am doing something wrong when it fails the validation. The page seems to be refreshing and hiding any error messages. It still doesn't work, @Alasdair.

Comment: I'm not sure what 'refreshing and hiding error messages means'. There might be something wrong with your view, but you haven't shown it so we can't tell.

Comment: I've updated my question adding the method responsible for writing a new comment.